# Checking if a user is logged in with PHP and javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am using a plugin userfrosting to manage users.

The PHP side of the app checks if the user is currently logged in.
The javascript side of the app checks what the permission of the user is.

EG.

```
<?php
 if (isUserLoggedIn()){
?>
   <script>
     loadCurrentUserPermission();
   </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Now that's fine and dandy, but now I want to implement some user access restrictions in my PHP files. Can I use such a method inside of a php function? Because I don't want to escape the PHP and check for every action.

The next option would be to store it in a variable, but how can I escape a variable assignment midway to the outcome of a < script > ?

```
$userPermission;
if (isUserLoggedIn()){
    $userPermission = (
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        userLoadPermissions();
    </script>
<?php
);
}
?>
```

Finally what if I use jquery to store the permission level in a PHP session ID? is that safe? Can someone easily modify their own level?

Comment: Users can't directly modify session variables, it's generally considered safe to store an access level in a session variable.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with `echo`ing the js?

```
<?php
    if (isUserLoggedIn()){
    echo "<script>loadCurrentUserPermission();</script>";

    // more php
?>
```

Edit: Oh, I see. Javascript, being server-side, will be loaded after the PHP, so it's not simple (or even possible) to have PHP, then JS, then more PHP execute on the same page. You could consider calling the rest of the PHP from somewhere else using an [AJAX request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4840022/3945798) but that might not be practical for all of your pages.